# DRY rspec test with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, routes, rspec-rails

I spent several hours trying to make my rspec test work. And as a result I got not really DRY tests which I want optimize somehow.

They look like the following:

```
describe ExtApi::BaseController do
  let!(:app)    { create(:api_application) }
  let!(:token)  { app.token }

  controller do
    def resp
      render json: {foo: 'bar'}
    end

    def error
      raise StandardError 'baz'
    end
  end

  describe '#authenticate' do
    context 'when is successfull' do
      it 'renders bar' do
        routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }
        get :resp,  access_token: token
        expect ...
      end
    end

    context 'when token is invalid' do
      before do
        app.destroy
      end

      it 'renders error' do
        routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }
        get :resp, access_token: token
        expect ...
      end

      it do
        routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }
        get :resp, access_token: token
        is_expected.to respond_with 401
      end
    end

    context 'when token is not presented' do
      it 'renders error' do
        routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }
        get :resp
        expect ...
      end

      it do
        routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }
        get :resp
        is_expected.to respond_with 401
      end
    end
  end
```

I have to repeat `routes.draw` in each `it` block (and not in `before`) because otherwise, it crushes all the routing, and in all tests that run after these ones, I get `RoutingError`.

So, I would like to know if there is any way to do this better than I do?

(I use `rails 4.2` and `rspec 3.4`)

Answer (score 1):

If you split your each controller test into a different block, you can do like this.

```
RSpec.describe ExtApi::BaseController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET resp" do
    it 'renders bar' do
      get :resp,  access_token: token
      # expect ...
    end
  end
end
```

reference: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: I don't see how  that would differ from what I have now

Comment: You don't have to write `routes.draw { get '/foo'  => 'ext_api/base#resp' }`     because Rspec handles that if it is a controller spec.